# Extracting summary data from various cells in R

Tags: r

Here is the Data:

```
data <-data.frame(
    "start"= c("go",NA,NA,NA,"go",NA,"go"),
    "number"= c(31,32,1,29,61,17,72),
    "info"= c("c","k","s","u","b","i","n"))

   start number info
1    go     31    c
2  <NA>     32    k
3  <NA>      1    s
4  <NA>     29    u
5    go     61    b
6  <NA>     17    i
7    go     72    n
```

And I want to produce a summary table that prints the **info** on each line where **Start** = "go"

However, I want the **Number** column to be summed from all the cells after a "go" until the next "go" so that the results look as follows:

```
final <- data.frame(
"start"=c("go","go","go"),
"number"=c(93,78,72),
"info"=c("c","b","n"))

   start number info
1    go     93    c
2    go     78    b
3    go     72    n
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For your data, don't use `cbind`. `data.frame("start"=...)` is sufficient and `cbind` will produce a character matrix so that the number variable will be converted to character and then to factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strategy in base R is to perform the subsetting and perform the summation in separate operations and then merge the results together. Here, we can use `cbind` for the merge, since the two datasets were constructed to line up.

```
cbind(data[!is.na(data$start), c(1, 3)],
      sum=aggregate(number ~ cumsum(!is.na(start)), data=data, sum)[,2])
  start info sum
1    go    c  93
5    go    b  78
7    go    n  72
```

I use `!is.na` to select the proper rows, which works in this example. If you have other, non-NA values you want excluded, you can use `!is.na(data$start) & data$start == "go"`. `aggregate` is used to perform the summation and the grouping in the second argument uses the same method, but performs a cumulative sum on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dplyr:

```
data <-data.frame(
  start= c("go",NA,NA,NA,"go",NA,"go"),
  number= c(31,32,1,29,61,17,72),
  info= c("c","k","s","u","b","i","n"),stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
data$group = cumsum(!is.na(data$start))
data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(n=sum(number), info=info[1])
```

Output

```
  group     n  info
1     1    93     c
2     2    78     b
3     3    72     n
```

Optionally you could add

```
 %>% mutate(start="go") %>% select(-group)
```

to get to your requested output, but I am not sure if that actually adds value. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here  is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(start = start[!is.na(start)], n = sum(number), 
     info = info[1]), .(grp = cumsum(!is.na(start)))][, grp := NULL][]
#   start  n info
#1:    go 93    c
#2:    go 78    b
#3:    go 72    n
```